# how to implement interface and extends in other class

Tags: java, android

I want to custom View.OnclickListener

in parent Class

```
public class parent implements View.onclickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("hello");
    }
}
```

in child Class

```
public class child extends Parent{ 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("morning");
    }
}
```

I wish it will show "hello" "morning" in Log
but it only show "morning",I check it's still from View.OnclickListenet, not from Parent Class

how could I custom Interface and use it ?

Comment: Your codes look weird. How could you "implement" something? Is that `extends`? Anyway if you want inherited functionality, you need to call `super` implementation via `super.onClick(v)`.

Comment: I forgot it...thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason only `morning` is printed because you are `Overriding` the `onClick`defined in your parent class. If you want to print both need to invoke the method from parent.

Call it as follows:

```
public class child extends Parent{ 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
        Log.i("morning");
    }
}
```

Comment: in project, there has so many onClick event, I need to avoid double Click issue, So  I try to custom onClick for other onClick

Comment: @NeilLin got it. Looks better idea now. Add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You override the **onclick()** method. So it will print 'morning' only. If you want print 'hello' also, then you should call super.onclick().

Thanks
AK